# "Last thing I'd do is" or "last thing I do would be"?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs, definite-article

If you want to say, for example, "If I were you, last thing I'd do is laugh" what is the correct usage of "would" here?

I've seen the above example but that doesn't sound quite right to me. Wouldn't this work: "... last thing I'd do would be to laugh"?

Or: "...last thing I do would be to laugh"?

Comment: The most common one is " The last thing I would if I were you is laugh"  The other option has two woulds which sounds redundant.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too but that "is" there seemed a little wrong to me for some reason. Thanks for your answer

Comment: "Is" here is necessary because  if you turn it into a question " What is the last thing you would do if you were me?" After "what" there is "is" so the answer should have "is",  other examples "The most I could do is"  "The most you will ever make of yourself is blow men like me"  "the harshest thing you could ever do to me is ..."  see  "is" here is necessary. :)

Comment: It's meant as a warning. Changing "is X" to "would be to X" softens the statement.

Comment: It sounds almost fine to me, but I would add a "the"
> "If I were you, the last thing I'd do is laugh"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common usage would be as follows:

> **Person A**: I challenge you to a race! 
>   **Person B**: Ha! You won't even make it halfway before I finish. 
>   **Person A**: If I were you, the last thing I would do is laugh.

I think this is more of a sort of idiom. This is the way it is said, and it has a particular connotation associated with it. While other options may be grammatically correct, the idiom needs to be said this way.